# Why placeholders in the bootstrap.yml are not resolved?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I'm getting below exception in my Spring project:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'MY_KEY' in value "${MY_KEY}"
org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:126)
```

This is how my bootstrap.yml looks like in src/main/resources/

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: native
  application:
    name: myapp 
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        health:
          enabled: false

encrypt:
#  key: ${MY_KEY}
  key: ${MY_KEY}
```

Other placeholders defined in application.yml are resolved correctly.

Following are the dependencies in my project:

```
spring-boot-starter:1.5.4.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter-config: -> 1.3.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-starter:1.2.2.RELEASE
spring-cloud-config-server: -> 1.3.1.RELEASE
spring-cloud-core:1.2.4.RELEASE
spring-cloud-config-client:1.3.1.RELEASE
```

Comment: How is `myKey` set? Where does it come from?

Comment: It comes from PCF environment variables

Comment: and the env var is formatted as `myKey` or `MY_KEY`?

Comment: @spencergibb in both places(PCF Env Var and bootstrap.yml) it's formatted as `MY_KEY `

Comment: ah, you are using unsupported versions :-(. try `${myKey:${MY_KEY}}`. If you were using boot 2 I would say use `${my-key}`.

Comment: wondering how it resolves other placeholders defined in `application.yml`. Sorry for the typo in the above `bootstrap.yml`, I just corrected it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210756/discussion-between-spencergibb-and-giri-col).